# How do I get django to recognise my admin.py file?

Tags: django-admin

I've create a separate file for admin models - how do I get django to look in the file? At the moment, the courses are not displayed in admin. Here's admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from website.apps.courses import Course

class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'start_date')

admin.site.register(Course, CourseAdmin)
```

Here's urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from website.apps.courses.views import *

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Admin panel and documentation:
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now solved. I hadn't imported the models from the admin.py file.